# retranslateUi() clears QLabel text

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, localization

My qt4-based application dynamically changes the GUI language by calling `retranslateUi()` function. It works like a charm, but when it processes the `QLabel` which text changes by the program, it tries to translate original text - the one, specified in Qt Designer, not the one, set by my program.

I understand it happens because `retranslateUi()` is auto-generated during build process so it couldn't possibly know about my changes, but I'd prefer to skip such `QLabel`s completely. Is there a way to tell Qt to skip certain widgets in `retranslateUi()`? Alternatively, maybe I can disable content change for `QLabel` in my program?

I know I can sub-class `QLabel` and by overriding `setText()` solve this problem, but I prefer to use standard `QLabel` to be able to manipulate it using Qt Designer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I remember, in Designer you can uncheck on QLabel should it be translated. By default it is. Choose label you don't want to be translated, in property editor scroll to "text" property, expand it and uncheck translate checkbox. Then you should generate ui_*.h file again. After that your label shouldn't be in retranslateUi code

Comment: I though there should be something like this but didn't look under `text`. That's exactly what I was looking for, many thanks!