# dynamically change text of tab created using Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, dynamic-properties

I have a dialog created using Qt Designer.

How can I make Qt Designer output something more dynamic than the hardcoded `"Survex Errors"` I18n key in the following code it generates?  (scroll to the right to see it)

For instance make it get the value of a dynamic property, or call a pure virtual function to get the key?

```
class Ui_cwImportTreeDataDialog
{
public:

    void setupUi(QDialog *cwImportTreeDataDialog)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

    void retranslateUi(QDialog *cwImportTreeDataDialog)
    {
        ...
        tabWidget->setTabText(tabWidget->indexOf(SurvexErrorsWidget), QApplication::translate("cwImportTreeDataDialog", "Survex Errors", 0));
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to be able to control which I18n key is used from my class that extends `Ui_cwImportTreeDataDialog`.

Comment: Can't you just reset the tabWidget->setTabText() in the constructor of cwImportTreeDataDialog?

Comment: Howdy!  I could, I was just looking for a way to do it that wouldn't get blown away if `retranslateUi` gets called later...

Comment: Check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426803/retranslateui-clears-qlabel-text

Comment: Ah.  Well, since the program is English only, I guess no loss...but I'd hope there's a way to make it work in any language

Comment: Currently we do have Chinese translations, but they aren't integrated into the master.